# Angular 10 No provider for ModalDialogService

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, ng-modules

recently I upgrated Angular 8 to Angular 10 and as it turns out I got one error which is:

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for ModalDialogService!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ModalDialogService -> ModalDialogService -> ModalDialogService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ModalDialogService!
```

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^10.1.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/qtip2": "^2.2.29",
    "adal-angular4": "^4.0.12",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.21",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ng-click-outside": "^5.3.0",
    "ng-custom-select": "^2.0.4",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.4",
    "ngx-modal-dialog": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^12.0.1",
    "qtip2": "^3.0.3",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-image-drop-module": "^1.0.3",
    "quill-image-resize": "^3.0.9",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  }
```

I register my Module like it is described in documentation:

```
    ModalDialogModule.forRoot()
```

I tried to downgrade @angular/cdk but nothing seems to help.
I triex ModalDialogService as a provider -- still no use.

Does any1 has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using **ModalDialogService** like that?:

```
constructor(modalService: ModalDialogService, viewRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
 
openNewDialog() {
  this.modalService.openDialog(this.viewRef, {
    title: 'Some modal title',
    childComponent: SimpleModalComponent
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey! 
Yes, exactly like that, but it is not working.

I should have mentioned that on Angular 8 it is working correctly without any problem, but when I updated CLI/Core to 10 it is giving me provider error...